# For a Fama-Macbeth regression , How does one predict the returns based on the model?

Tags: regression, factor-models

Fama-Macbeth does a two-step regression i.e a time-series and cross-sectional regression and we estimate betas and lambdas, so how does one predict based on these parameters, which one to choose?

Comment: Please add the formula or at least a reference ... what are the Lambdas?

Answer (score 3):

Those are not predictive models. Fama-MacBeth just checks whether the model is valid unconditionally. 
Chapter 12 from Cochrane book is a good reference.